# Yarn: unable to clone private github repo. ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have a private repo on github with dependencies on other private github repos and `npm install` installs all the dependencies without problems.

I installed Yarn (on MacOS) and tried to run `yarn` in the command line, but it failed cloning the private dependencies with the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

How do I make yarn install the modules? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now Yarn doesn't support installation from [private package](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/521)  and [private github repo](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/573)

There is a [workaround](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/513#issuecomment-253010084) provided by [Milos Ivanovic](https://github.com/milosivanovic):

> If you add the following to your ~/.ssh/config file:
>
> ```
> Host github.com
>     User git
> ```
>
> you can force all logins to github.com via SSH to use the user git by >default, and this makes yarn able to clone from
>   private repositories when using the ssh://github.com//
>   source format.

Fortunately this is just a matter of time before yarn support private repo on github, as there is already a [pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/971) for it.

Answer (score 13):

Yarn@0.16.0 works by replacing the url of type

```
"private-test": "git+ssh://git@github.com:ramasilveyra/private-test.git#d6c5789"
```

with

```
"private-test": "git+ssh://git@github.com/ramasilveyra/private-test.git#d6c5789"
```

Replace `:` colon with `/` to make it work.

Comment: This one is better at the moment, since it also resolved the issue when one is using `bitbucket`, thanks

Comment: Awesome just want I was looking for

Comment: Nice. I've also gotten it to work on yarn v0.19.1 with the colon as long as their is a leading `/` for the path, i.e. `"private-test": "git+ssh://git@github.com:/ramasilveyra/private-test.git#d6c5789"`

Comment: Thank you so much!